# Dart / Flutter Conditional Named Parameters

Tags: flutter, dart

In Javascript, to conditionally add a value to an Object, I can do something like this:

```js
const obj = {
   ...(myCondition && {someKey: "someValue"})
}
```

Can I do something similar to pass in a named parameter in Dart / Flutter?  For example, if I have the below code, is there a way to conditionally pass the `place` parameter only if it exists in the `json` passed into the `fromJson` factory function.

```dart
factory SearchResult.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SearchResult(
      id: json['id'],
      displayString: json['displayString'],
      name: json['name'],
      recordType: json['recordType'],
      collection: json['collection'],
      place: GeoJson.fromJson(json['place']),
      properties: json['properties']
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is not passing value to named parameter different from passing null instead? Because I usually do something like place: GeoJson.fromJson(json['place']) ?? null

Comment: @FederickJonathan that's a good point.  The problem that I face is that if I pass `null`, the `GeoJson.fromJson` method throws an error because it expects a value.  Is there a way to allow a value to be a `String` or `null` kind of like in Typescript you can say `private someAttribute: string | null`.

Comment: In that case, you could do bool isPlaceNotEmpty = json['place'] != null. Then place: isPlaceNotEmpty ? GeoJson.fromJson(json['place']) : null. You won't call fromJson and passing null value this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for Dart's [collection operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators), specifically *collection-if* and *collection-for* capabilities.

You can, for example do something like:

```
final map = {
  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2',
  if (myCondition) 'key3': 'value3'
};
```

This works in lists, too:

```dart
final list = ['value1', 'value2', if (myCondition) 'value3'];
```

In this case, you might be after something along the lines of:

```dart
final keys = [
  'id',
  'displayString',
  'name',
  'recordType',
  'collection',
  'place',
  'properties'
],
obj = {for (final key in keys) if (json.containsKey(key)) key: json[key]};
```

Comment: That's for sure helpful.  Though, I am trying to figure out a way to conditionally (if it exists) pass a parameter to the `fromJson` method above rather than add it to an object.  Seems my only option might be to handle the `null` when passing values in.

Answer (score 0):

```
factory SearchResult.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var isNotEmpty = json['place'] != null;

    return SearchResult(
      id: json['id'],
      displayString: json['displayString'],
      name: json['name'],
      recordType: json['recordType'],
      collection: json['collection'],
      /// This way you won't call fromJson and passing null if json['place'] is null in the first place
      place: isNotEmpty ? GeoJson.fromJson(json['place']) : null,
      properties: json['properties']
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In dart if you receive a `null` object you can use double question mark operator:

- ??

What it means? : If `object` is `null` then take what it is after double question mark

```
var b = null;
var a = b ?? 'b was null, you got me!';
print(a);
```

result:

a: `b was null, you got me!`

For example:

```
factory SearchResult.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var isNotEmpty = json['place'] != null;

    return SearchResult(
      id: json['id'] ?? 0,
      displayString: json['displayString'] ?? '',
      name: json['name'] ?? '',
      recordType: json['recordType'] ?? '',
      collection: json['collection'] ? '',
      place: GeoJson.fromJson(json['place'] ?? {}),
      properties: json['properties'] ?? [],
    );
  }
```

Null safe types are fun to use